# Propel ORM Documentation as PDF

Tags: pdf, documentation, pdf-generation, markdown, propel

is there a possibility to convert a markdown written documentation (https://github.com/propelorm/propelorm.github.com) to a pdf file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you print it? If so, use a PDF printer driver, perhaps CutePDF or similar.

Comment: It's a website consisting of many different pages, so printing is quite difficult. Have a look here: http://propelorm.org/documentation/

Comment: I printed the pages to pdf with google chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Consider converting from Markdown to HTML, and then from HTML to PDF; I use [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) and [DOMPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) respectively for each task. This approach allows you to apply styling using CSS. I tried converting directly, but didn't seem to have much luck.

I have [some Markdown documentation](https://github.com/halfer/php-training-course/tree/master/source/en/docs) which I convert as above using [this script](https://github.com/halfer/php-training-course/blob/master/source/en/build.sh) - I need to do a little more work on it, but I'm 99% happy with it. Give that a go?

If you get this working, ping me - it would be great to set up a simple site to mirror the official Propel docs with a PDF!